# How to hide product price from Google search

Tags: magento2

In my site we set product price & Add to cart button hide.
If customer login then they show price and Add to cart button.
It's properly working in our site.
But when we search product in google; then we show price.
Any one help me for hide product price from Google search.

Comment: How do you hide price, with LESS style?

Comment: Any type of solutin need. If is it using css or using code.

Answer (score 0):

You may explore https://mobecls.com/microdata-magento-product/

Look for some `<meta itemprop="price"` or `<meta itemprop='price'` in your templates